# Cómo puedo usar CASE en un procedimiento SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Tengo un procedimiento en SQL para **seleccionar alojamientos** dentro de un rango de fechas, con el fin de poder reservarlos. Quiero que los alojamientos **se filtren según la provincia** en la que estén, en mi caso solo existen dos provincias: *'Cáceres'* y *'Badajoz'*.
Mi intención es que el procedimiento reciba **tres parámetros**: *fecha de inicio*, *fecha final* y un *número* (***1 para Cáceres, 2 para Badajoz, y en otro caso que devuelva todos los alojamientos***).
He pensado usar **CASE**, pero no lo consigo sacar. ¿Alguien sabe cómo podría hacerlo? Gracias.
Esto es lo que llevo hecho.
**Parámetros:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT codigo,nombre,provincia,pueblo,ruta FROM imgprincipal_alojamiento 
INNER JOIN reserva
ON codigo = reserva.alojamiento
INNER JOIN habitaciones
ON habitaciones.numero = reserva.habitacion
WHERE
(inicio>=CURRENT_DATE or final>=CURRENT_DATE) AND
(inicioReserva NOT BETWEEN inicio AND final) OR (finalReserva NOT BETWEEN inicio AND final);
END
```

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que llevas hecho.

Comment: ¿MySQL o SQLlite? ¿Nos pasas el dataset?

Comment: @Marcos ya están hechos los cambios.

Comment: @DavidJP es SQL.

Comment: ¿Puedes utilizar phpMyAdmin -> Exportar para pasarnos la estructura de tu base de datos en .sql con unos datos de ejemplo y el resultado que esperas obtener?